# How to extract a token value which is available only in Inspect elements-> Application (Not in Inspect Elements-> Network) thru Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, json-extract

How to extract a token value which is available only in Inspect elements-> Application (Not in Inspect Elements-> Network) thru Jmeter?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The access token value is available in the response headers. You can use a post-processor element to extract the access token from the header.

Here is an example to extract the access token using a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) Post-processor

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It comes as a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) so the easiest way to extract it is to:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick the change from point 2
4. Once done you should be able to access the token as `${COOKIE_accesstoken}` where required

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference - Miscellaneous configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)